# One of the Four Check box not Working in C#

Tags: c#, checkbox

I've written a code in which when one check box is clicked the others get disselected 
[image of  buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wmf6.png)
3 of my check boxes are working fine byname,containing and bydate But when I try to do the same with the by category check box I get the following message.[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiYhL.png)
This is my code

```
 private void vieworder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            lblstatus.Text = "Connected";
            lblstatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }
        else
        {
            lblstatus.Text = "Not-Connected";
            lblstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
        showdtgrid();



    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}

private void hidecheckbox()
{
    chkboxbyname.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    chkboxbydate.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    chkboxcontaining.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
    checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;

}





private void chkboxbyname_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        hidecheckbox();

        chkboxbyname.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

}

private void chkboxcontaining_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        hidecheckbox();

    chkboxcontaining.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;

}

private void chkboxbydate_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        hidecheckbox();

    chkboxbydate.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;


}
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    hidecheckbox();
    checkBox1.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
}


   }
```

}

Please tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like the stack overflow is directly related to the event handler for *checkBox1_CheckedChanged*.

It looks like that handler is calling *hideCheckbox()*, which in turn changes the *CheckState* of your checkbox to *Unchecked*. That would in turn fire off your event handler, and therefore create an infinite loop.

What's strange is that you claim everything is working for the other checkboxes. My guess is that those checkboxes aren't wired up to their corresponding event handlers, as they should also cause stack overflow.

Could you try removing your event handler entirely if it isn't needed? Otherwise, comment out the call to *hideCheckbox()*

Comment: as I said Every other check box is working fine except this _CheckBox1_